# Conexão Node.js com Oracle 11g

Tags: node.js, oracle

Estou tentando fazer a conexão da minha aplicação Node.js com um database Oracle 11g, estou recebendo o seguinte erro.

> PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\PROJETO WEB> node oracle.js
> Error: NJS-138: connections to this database server version are not supported by node-oracledb in Thin mode
> at Object.throwErr (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PROJETO WEB\node_modules\oracledb\lib\errors.js:592:10)
> at ThinConnectionImpl.connect (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PROJETO WEB\node_modules\oracledb\lib\thin\connection.js:537:14)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async Object.getConnection (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PROJETO WEB\node_modules\oracledb\lib\oracledb.js:628:3)
> at async connectAndQuery (C:\Users\user\Desktop\PROJETO WEB\oracle.js:8:11) {
> code: 'NJS-138'
> }

module oracledb: 6.0.3 
db version: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production 
Node version: v18.16.1

````
oracledb.outFormat - oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;

async function connectAndQuery() {
  let con;

  try {
    con = await oracledb.getConnection( {
      user: 'usuario',
      password: 'senha',
      connectString: `
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ip)(PORT = porta))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVER = DEDICATED)
          (SERVICE_NAME = DBPROD)
        )
      )
    `,
    })

    const data = await con.execute(
        'SELECT * FROM TSIUSU WHERE CODUSU = 372',
    );

    console.log(data.rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
// Chama a função para conectar e consultar o banco de dados
connectAndQuery(); ```
````

Answer (score -3, accepted):

É por conta da versão do seu banco de dados. O modulo oracledb v6.0.3 tem suporte somente para o banco oracle v12.1 ou versões superiores. Veja nesse link: https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/appendix_a.html#oracle-database-features-supported-by-node-oracledb

Você pode atualizar seu banco de dados ou habilitar do [Thick Mode](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#enabling-node-oracledb-thick-mode) que faz com você tenha suporte do Oracle Database 9.2 para frente. Caso esse exemplo não ficado muito claro como deve ser feito, achei um exemplo mais sensato em código [aqui](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/example.js#L47-L63).

No exemplo acima. Você precisa setar uma variável na sua .env chamada `NODE_ORACLEDB_DRIVER_MODE=thick`. O resto é como tá ali mostrando.

Eu peguei a referência para essa resposta em uma duplicata: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76429211/21148569

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda fui seguindos os tópicos informados e consegui resolver meu problema, foi necessario baixar uma lib instantclient_19_18 para fazer a conexão com oracle 11g